# How to save android logs in database through aspects using aspectj

Tags: android, sqlite, aop, aspectj

Hi all i have created aspect for error logging which logs error when any exception is thrown, but i want to save the log in sqllite database android but how to do that in aspect.

Following is my aspect code:

```
public aspect ErrorLog {

    private long startTime, endTime, elapsedTime;
    private Signature sig;
    private String line, sourceName;

    pointcut publicCalls() : (execution(* *(..))&& !cflow(within(Trace)));

    before(): publicCalls(){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    after(): publicCalls(){
        if (LogConfig.isTraceEnabled) {
            sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
            line = "" + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getLine();
            sourceName = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation()
                    .getWithinType().getCanonicalName();
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    after() throwing(Throwable e) : publicCalls() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(endTime);
        Logger.getLogger("Error").log(
                Level.SEVERE,
                "[XPLOGGER]: " + "Time: " + calendar.getTime() + " Class: "
                        + sourceName + " Line No.: " + line + " MethodName: "
                        + sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + sig.getName()
                        + " Exception: " + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `Logger.getLogger()` from `java.util.logging`? In that case you might best be served adding a custom [`Handler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) to the logger in question. You might also try to switch to a different logging library that has logging to SQL already included (e.g. slf4j or logback).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I am creating my own library above code is from library so i have to save it from here.

Comment: @YogeshShinde could i please know what is the value of startTime you are getting whenever there is new method execution. I just used this piece of code and I am getting the startTime to be constant always